# How can convert 255 into '\xff'?

Tags: python-3.x

To convert 255 into 'ff':

```
f'{255:02x}'
'ff'
```

To convert 255 into '0xff':

```
f'{255:#02x}'
'0xff'
```

To convert 255 into `b'\xff':

```
bytes.fromhex('ff')
b'\xff'
```

How can convert 255 into `'\xff` without `b` at the beginning of `b'\xff'`?

Comment: print(f"\\x{255:02x}")

Comment: Use `chr(255)`.

Comment: @S.B because that’s the character `'\xff'` creates.  Does the OP want the 4-character string `'\\xff'`? It is unclear

Answer (score 0):

```
chr(255) == '\xff'
True
f"\\x{255:02x}" == '\xff'
False
```

So,i got the answer `chr(255)`,so simple,why i can't get?!